# Extending a Separator (Deriving from)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, extends

I have to implement a custom `Separator`, with a few custom properties (the main one is a `Header`):

```
public class HeaderedSeparator : Separator
{
    //More properties here... HeaderForeground and SeparatorHeight.
    public static readonly DependencyProperty HeaderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Header", typeof(string), typeof(HeaderedSeparator));

    [Bindable(true), Category("Common")]
    public string Header
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HeaderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HeaderProperty, value); }
    }

    static HeaderedSeparator()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HeaderedSeparator), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HeaderedSeparator)));
    }
}
```

And the `Style` (inside the Themes\Generic.xaml):

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type c:HeaderedSeparator}">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="SeparatorHeight" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFE0E3E6"/>
    <Setter Property="HeaderForeground" Value="#FF202326"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type c:HeaderedSeparator}">
                <Grid Margin="0,4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding HeaderForeground}"/>

                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Height="{TemplateBinding SeparatorHeight}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                               VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                               Stretch="Fill"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

(Edit) Usage:

```
<c:HeaderedSeparator Header="Itens"/>
```

This separator is supposed to display a Header while being used inside a menu. That's why I'm using the `Key` attribute, but for some reason, this isn't working (The default style is being loaded). Do you guys know why?

Comment: Try to use '{x:Type c:HeaderedSeparator}' as x:Key or leave it empty

Comment: Both have no different results, they display the same default style.

Comment: Can you please add the XAML snippet where you use the headered separator?